# Update the thousand separator commas when the input values are changed in Angular reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

The link to the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-csqein?file=src/app/hello.component.html

When I copy-paste a value into the INPUT box it returns the correct data

INPUT - 12345678 OUTPUT - 12,345,678

but when I input values one by one it is not able to format it
the output looks like this 1,234567

Expected OUTPUT

1. When the input is first loaded it comes with the comma-separated digits.
2. I want to make it so that when the users add or delete values in the input box, the commas are updated in the very box.

Things that I have tried

1. Creating custom Pipe and updating the value in the component using valueChanges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't transform input value when you using `formControlName`, because when you want to transform that value, angular give you a formControl that you can use to change that value.

For example in your code, you can do this:

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) {}
profileForm;
ngOnInit() {
  this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
    name: this.currencyPipe.transform(12345678, '', '','0.0'),
  });

  // this.changes();
}
```

Note: Don't forget to provide `CurrencyPipe` in your module.

The code above it's the only way or solution you can do to change the input value when you use the formControlName.

Or another way you can use is remove your `formControlName` from your input and it will working fine.

```js
<input
    id="number"
    [value]="profileForm.get('name').value | number"
    maxlength="8"
  />
```

But the problem is you should have to do it manually to patch value from input to your formControl. You can use `(input)` like what I do in custom input component below.

**Custom Input Component**

If you like to using custom input component, then code below maybe can help you to resolve your question:

You can create `app-input.ts` and put this code below:

```js
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';
import {
  Component,
  forwardRef,
  HostListener,
  Input,
  OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ControlContainer,
  ControlValueAccessor,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input[type=currency]',
  templateUrl: './currency.component.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CurrencyComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class CurrencyComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
  @Input() formControlName: string;
  value: any;
  onChange: () => any;
  onTouche: () => any;

  public formGroup: FormGroup;
  public formControl: FormControl;

  constructor(
    private controlContainer: ControlContainer,
    private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Currency Component');
    console.log(this.controlContainer);
    this.setStateInitialization();
  }

  private setStateInitialization(): void {
    this.formGroup = this.controlContainer.control as FormGroup;
    this.formControl = this.formGroup.get(this.formControlName) as FormControl;
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.value = value;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouche = fn;
  }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  private _onHostListenerInput(event: InputEvent): void {
    const inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    let value: string | number = inputElement.value;
    if (value) value = +inputElement.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    this.formControl.patchValue(value);
    inputElement.value = value
      ? this.currencyPipe.transform(value, '', '', '0.0')
      : '';
  }
}
```

Now you can add `app-input.html` and use code below:

```html
<input
  type="text"
  [value]="formControl.value ? (formControl.value | currency: '':'':'0.0') : ''"
/>
```

After that if you want to use this component, you can call:

```html
<app-input type="currency" formControlName="currency"></app-input>
```

Or whatever name you want, you can change it.

**Update:**

Live Preview: https://angular-ivy-aqppd6.stackblitz.io

Live Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aqppd6?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I hope it can help you to imagine what you can do to resolve your question.

Comment: Hi thank you so much, could you please explain to me why it wasn't working and just a little about how did go on to fix it ?

Comment: I will update my answer to answer your question

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula, from Angular 12 (I not remember if in Angular 11 yet you can) you can import directly [formatCurrency](https://angular.io/api/common/formatCurrency) from '@angular/common' to not inject the currency pipe. just: `name: formatCurrency.transform(12345678, 'en-US', '','0.0')`

Comment: @Eliseo, in angular 14 we must provide.